# Can't create table in django database

Tags: python, django, web

Hello guys I am trying to create table in django database or in other word I am trying to syncdb but here is the error I encounter

```
-bash-3.2$ ~/html/ENV/bin/python2.7 manage.py syncdb
Creating tables ...
Creating table red_carpet_contactus
ValueError: The database backend does not accept 0 as a value for AutoField.
```

and here is the models file

```
from django.db import models
#from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Page (models.Model):
    Info= models.TextField()
    page_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % self.page_name

class category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" %(self.category_name)


class contactus(models.Model):
    PageName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Phone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Mob = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Fax = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" %(self.page_name)

class gallery(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    picture = models.FileField(upload_to='photos/')
    thumbnail = models.FileField(upload_to='thumbnail/', blank=True, null=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % self.picture.url


class images(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='images/')

#addition of the main page logo
class Main_page_img(models.Model):
    logo = models.FileField(upload_to='images/')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % self.logo.url

class fields_class(models.Model):
    data = models.TextField()
    content = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % self.content


class trips_main_data(models.Model):
    image = models.ManyToManyField(gallery)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    trip_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country_info = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    trip_info = models.TextField()
    fields = models.ManyToManyField(fields_class,blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(category)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % self.trip_name
```

So would u suggest me guys to how to solve this problem??

Comment: Please include a Django version and which DB backend you are using.

Comment: Coding standards? Please change property names so that all of them start with a lowercase character.

Comment: you have a `carpet` model somewhere dont you? Could we see it?

Comment: @Iqc I Am using django 1.4 and I am using mysql as backend